# Rails 4: small N+1 issue for uncached page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a some code that is generating an N+1 database querying issue.

The issue only occurs if the page is uncached. Once the page is cached, adding an `.includes` actually results in an unnecessary database call. I'm wondering how to get around this problem.

my **applicaiton_helper.rb** contains the following:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def by(article)
    "By #{article.username} on #{article.created_at.strftime('%B %e, %Y')}"
  end
end
```

my **article.rb** contains:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def username
    user.username
  end
end
```

and my **articles_controller.rb** contains:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = user_signed_in? ? Article.all : Article.all.published.limit(13)
  end
end
```

The method in question is the `username` method, which makes a call to the User model. As aforementioned, when the page hasn't already been cached, this results in the `by(article)` helper method to make continuous calls to the User model without any eager loading. However, since I am caching my views, this inefficiency only occurs once. If I change my articles_controller.rb to the following:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = user_signed_in? ? Article.all.includes(:user) : Article.all.published.limit(13).includes(:user)
  end
end
```

the N+1 issue disappears on the first page load, but then I get an unnecessary `.includes` upon reloading the page.

Any idea how I can fix this small glitch?

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't really mate sense. `includes` should use one query to load the users. Something else is probably going on. Are you enabling caching in development to test this?

Comment: I feel like it is the `article.username` call causing this to look up in the model via an additional request.

Comment: @Mohamad I just disabled caching in development. I now consistently get a message from Bullet saying
```N+1 Query detected
  Article => [:user]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:user]
N+1 Query method call stack
  ~/myapp/app/models/article.rb:64:in `username'```

Comment: I can confirm that adding `.includes(:user)` to my controller gets rid of the message (with disabled cache). Re-enabling the cache results in this message: `Unused Eager Loading detected
  Article => [:user]
  Remove from your finder: :includes => [:user]`...mind boggling @_@

Comment: That log in my opinion means: call `article.user.username` instead of `article.username`, it points you to the `username` method.

Comment: @jbehrens94 `article.username` simply calls `self.user.username`, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with trying?
Bullet tells you that the call stack is article.rb (model) in the method username. Should be enough.

Comment: @jbehrens94 tried now, doesn't make a difference :/

Comment: @DaniG2k - How do you perform caching here? Your controller only creates the relation, as long as it is not used within a view it should not trigger any calls.

Comment: @jbehrens94 rails should know that `article#username` points to `article.user` in the memory. So this is not the issue. Something else is going on.

Comment: The message `Unused Eager Loading detected ...` is a (closed) issue from `Bullet`, see more [here](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet/issues/147)

Comment: @DanielBatalla thanks for that. I was actually just starting to think this may be a bug in Bullet and not an actual issue on my side. I will report it with a link to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow this has solved my problem:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :username, to: :user
end
```

So I simply delegate the username call on an article to the User model. Beautiful, clean and does the trick: bullet no longer complains.

Answer (score 0):

I've just came to a crazy solution: your could check if cached fragment exist in controller. But the problem is that Rails automatically adds a file digest to cache key. So, my "solution": change caching way to smth like this

```
# in your view:
<% cache 'foo', skip_digest: true do %>
  contents
<% end %>
```

And then in controller you could check if fragment is already cached:

```
def index
  if fragment_exist?('asd')
    @articles = user_signed_in? ? Article.all : Article.published.limit(13)
  else
    @articles = user_signed_in? ? Article.all.includes(:user) : Article.published.limit(13).includes(:user)
  end
end
```

Obviously, turning off digests isn't very good solution: while solving your current problem it adds a new one. But it works :)

I couldn't find a way to get view digest in controller, but anyway I think it would be overkill for such a small problem as one-time-occured N+1. And if what bothers you is only `bullet` warnings you may [turn them off](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet#whitelist) for particular action.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually think the problem may be with Bullet and not with using `.includes(:user)`. I will report it and see what they think.

Comment: As for me, `bullet` is right in this case, 'cause when the page is cached `includes` is unnecessary indeed. But as since you know about it and it's desired behavior you may just turn the warning off.